# Sticking a button on the bottom right

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Picture of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmRcw.png)

I'm making this project for my bootcamp, and I'm struggling with moving this `+ button` to the bottom right of this container. My project has this container to **simulate** a phone screen. I have a sub-content box for it and everything, but I'm struggling with having the button on the bottom right above the footer, sticking to it. At the moment, its always stuck to each "mission" I create.

```css
.bottom-right-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; 
}
```

I've tried this, but doing it makes the button appear on the bottom right of the actual page, not the **simulation** of the phone screen

Comment: If the "simulation" of the phone screen is it's own element just make it `position:relative` That should lock the button within it's box.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever div you want to align:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Whichever div you will accept as a reference:

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey there! 

I've tried and it sort of works, the div that accepts it as a reference has a certain size: .sub-content-box {
    height: calc(100% - 125px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

My issue now is that, I want to have it be sticky on the bottom right above the footer which is being rendered in ruby on rails, so when this content box becomes scrollable, the button is always visible there, because like this when it's scrollable it's always in that same position

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the question (a little code would be nice) but you may be looking for position: fixed to position the button relative to the viewport

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0}

#app {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
}


main {
  background: whitesmoke;
  min-height: 300vh; /* force scroll to test */ 
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, slategray); 
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  inset: auto 0 0;
  height: 3rem;
  background: silver;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4rem; /* include nav height to place above */
  right: 1rem;
  appearance: none;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <main>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <button>+</button>
  </main>
  <nav>
    Navigation
  </nav>
</div>
```